# How do I build a dict from key-value pair list?

Tags: python

I am using boto3 to get the EC2 instance tags which has the form

```py
[{u'Value': 'swarm manager 0', u'Key': 'Name'}, {u'Value': 'manager', u'Key': 'Role'}]
```

I want to convert that to a dict like this

```py
{'Name': 'swarm manager 0', 'Role': 'manager'}
```

Here's my code

```py
tags = [{u'Value': 'swarm manager 0', u'Key': 'Name'}, {u'Value': 'manager', u'Key': 'Role'}]
tag_dict = dict()
for tag in tags:
  tag_dict[tag['Key']]=tag['Value']
print(tag_dict)
```

and https://repl.it/@trajano/GargantuanStickyNasm

Seems a bit wordy, I am thinking there should be a one or two line python thing to do that conversion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Dict comprehensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) are a thing:

```
tag_dict = {tag['Key']: tag['Value'] for tag in tags}
```

Comment: I chose this approach as it is the most direct and the easiest to read.  https://github.com/trajano/terraform-docker-swarm-aws/blob/b6f9654465533098d7e49ebfa025b53393a29e75/init_node.py#L67-L71

Answer (score 2):

Similar to comprehensions, `dict` accepts an iterable of pairs, which can be a comprehension as well:

```
from operator import itemgetter
dict(map(itemgetter('Key', 'Value'), tags))
```

OR

```
dict(itemgetter('Key', 'Value')(x) for x in tags)
```

In python 3.6+, dicts are ordered, so if your dictionary always has `'Value'` before `'Key'`, you can do

```
dict(x.values()[::-1] for x in tags)
```

Of course this latter method is not worth using in a production environment as it is too unreliable.

Comment: Could also replace `lambda x: (x['Key'], x['Value'])` with `operator.itemgetter('Key', 'Value')`.

Comment: @MarioIshac. Nice catch. TIL that you can get multiple items all at once.